# How can I refill a gas canister?

Tags: unturned

In previous versions of Unturned, one could refill gas canisters at specific places on the map, at huge gas tanks.

In the new default map of version 3.0, I have yet to find such gas tanks.

**How and where can the gas canisters be refilled in the new map?**

Comment: Note: I intentionally added *Unturned 3* to the title, since there is no specific tag for version 3 and it may be useful to distinguish outdated information from new information about version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to a gas station, hold the gas can in your hand, and use a fuel pump [image: A fuel pump, found near a gas station]

or you can use a fuel tank, looks white, and is around areas like farms and the military base.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to gas station and press right click with portable gas can or industrial gas can while pointing on fuel pump or any venicle that have gas.You can see how many procents on gas is left while you point on any venicle or gas pump.When you want to refill gas to your car, point with portable or industrial gas can on your car and click left click.